# index not creating while using multiple JDBC Inputs in Linux environment

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-jdbc

hi while trying to create index using logstash with multiple JDBC
inputs  ,unable to create Index  in linux environment ..but it works
on Windows  .  Index created on windows system  ....but on  Cento-os index is creating as follows   %{type}

```
 input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/Users/logstash/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name"
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => "password"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "select * from table1"
    type => "table1"
  }
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/Users/logstash/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name"
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => "password"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "select * from table2"
    type => "table2"
  }
  # add more jdbc inputs to suit your needs 
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => "%{type}"
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of the stack are you using in each environment? Since version 6.X you can have only one `type` per index, you can't have the setting `document_type` trying to set different types for the same index.

Comment: 6.4.2 @leandrojmp

Comment: found the  solution for this can Add tags by replacing type    if "table" in [tags] output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => "ABC"
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

found the solution for this can Add tags by replacing type 
tags =>"table1"  # replace the type with tags  in input of every jdbc

add the following code for output

```
output {
    if "table1" in [tags] {
 elasticsearch {
 index => "ABC"
 hosts => "localhost:9200" 
} } 

if "table2" in [tags] {
 elasticsearch {
 index => "CBA"
 hosts => "localhost:9200" 
} } 
 }
```